# UNITY 3D - Get X and Y components relative to a value and an angle

Tags: unity, angles

I have an algorithm, that, once the gameObject collides with a trigger, a method is called, on which the current collectibles (almonds) picked are instanciated around the circular area of the gameObject on the (x,y) plane. The spawning distribution is correct (at least that seems to be). The problem is the translation, I want to push each almond relative to the Y Axis of the object, so I figured out that with geometry I could take both x, y component for a vector with the angles, then to pass that Vector3 to the DOMove method (I am also using DOTween).

Maybe the approach isn't the right one, or maybe the trigonometric functions change relative to the position.

Here is the code that spawns and translates each almond:

```
public void takeAlmondsAway() //Will take as parameter the current position of the nerve impulse when it's backed after collision...
{
    int quant = gm.getAlmondsScore(); //The quantity of almonds that will be taken away from the player, relative to the almonds score, duh...
    float angle = 360 / quant; //The angle distribution each individual almond will have when instanciated, the iterator will multiply the angle...
    GameObject[] almonds = new GameObject[quant];
    Vector3 tempMov;
    float tempX;
    float tempY;
    int distance = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i < quant; i++)
    {
        Quaternion rot = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, (angle * (i + 1))); //The i jump will be necessary here since we care about the i values from 1 to 'quant'

        if(rot.z > 180) rot.z -= 360; //Since the transform rotation goes from 180 to -180, we have to caompensate it with the minus 360 to get the inverse...

        almonds[i] = (GameObject)Instantiate(almond, this.transform.position, this.transform.rotation);
        almonds[i].transform.localRotation = rot;

        //Trying to, based on the prediction distance vector, determine the x & y components needed for the DoMove parameters...
        tempX = Mathf.Cos((angle * (i + 1)) * Mathf.Rad2Deg) * distance;
        tempY = Mathf.Sin((angle * (i + 1)) * Mathf.Rad2Deg) * distance;

        Debug.Log("X: " + tempX);
        Debug.Log("Y: " + tempY);

        //tempMov = new Vector3(almonds[i].transform.localPosition.x, almonds[i].transform.localPosition.y+5, almonds[i].transform.localPosition.z);
        tempMov = new Vector3(tempX, tempY, almonds[i].transform.position.z);

        almonds[i].transform.DOMove(tempMov, 0.5f);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is the translation, but what's the problem with the translation?

Comment: oh yeah, sorry, maybe I didn't explained that part pretty well....mmmm lets say that I want the almonds to have all a simetric movement....mmmm that each one was in the same distance of the gameObject but relative to its position after the circular spawn distribution...or maybe a image would help?

Comment: Yes, likely a few images. Show us what's happening now and what you want to have. Then tell us how what you're trying now isn't working.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer. Well, this is the result of the code as I showed [link](http://imgur.com/swJlFKv). The second image is without the DOMove, just spawning the almonds around a circular area relative to the gameObject (in the image the gameObject is pushed backwards after spawning the almonds), with the thing I was planing to do (to get both X and Y components relative to the angle, taking the hypotenuse  as the value distance, on this case 1) [link](http://imgur.com/YlcutOO)